# OAuth: Client revoking access of several access tokens

Tags: security, oauth, oauth-2.0, access-token

Suppose I am a client application and I request resource owners to share their resources using Authorization servers(and resource servers) like Facebook and Google. Lets assume that some of my access tokens were compromised. In that case, Can I request Facebook or Google to revoke all those tokens?
(I already know that tokens are short lived. But can we revoke access. I tried looking it up on Facebook developer section/ Stack Overflow and did not stumble upon anything on this)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Access tokens are short lived normally an hour.  There is an expiration within the access token

```
{
  "nbf": 1528875493,
  "exp": 1528875793,
   .......
}
```

Exp tells you when the access token will expire.  The are not actually stored on the servers anywhere. So no there is no way for Facebook or Google to revoke an access token.    because access tokens are short lived it is assumed that they are reasonably secure because if someone does get a hold of your access token there is a very limited amount of time where they can use it.